# Heroku Time Out

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-cli

I created a django app which works perfectly fine in localhost. The SQL server is in GoogleCloud SQL.

There is a simple student form registration, for which I create a form using forms.ModelForm.

I use logger to find if it passed/failed the is_valid() constraint. Something like,

```
if form.is_valid():
   logging.info("passed")
   student = form.save()
   logging.info("Saved")
else:
   logging.error("Failed")
```

When I try with local host, it works fine in getting the POST data and creating objects in the Cloud server, but using heroku, it gets timed out.
It does retrieve the POST data but times out even during checking the form, and not even print the log line of passed, giving out a timeout, but it shouldn't be a trouble regarding the SQL server because it didn't log the line in the first place to move to next step, and SQL connectivity works fine in localhost too in creating objects and posting.

It throws 503 in

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/student/register/" host=x-y.herokuapp.com request_id=----f43d65a33f03 fwd="98.210.122.173" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```